# SQLce DAL, Linq-to-Sql or EntityFramework

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm learning databases, using SqlCe, and need business object to database mapping.

Currently I try to decide if to use Linq to Sql, or EntityFramework. (I understand a bit L2S, but haven't familiarized with EF yet)

The program will only be developed and used by myself, so I have good control of the priorities:

1. I don't need to consider potential change of database type or data storage type, as I'm quite certain SQLce will stay sufficient.
2. I DO expect continued development and changes to the data scheme while the program is in active use; change business object properties (Hence database columns), and possibly overall table scheme. So old data must be transported to new scheme.

I also want to keep a decent degree of layer separation DAL/BLL, although this may not be necessary, it is good for me to learn these principles.

My question is: With these priorities, would I have any benefit by choosing either Linq2Sql vs. EntityFramwork?  (and please explain why)

Btw, the project involves very simple table scheme and relations with only ~4 tables total.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use Linq to sql for this,actually linq to sql is the subset of adoentity framnework.
as per ur need its better to use linq to sql becoz ur database is not complicated as well it just have some tables. linq to sql is easy to use in respect to adoentitiesframeowrk

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Linq2Sql only works with MS SQL Server out of the box, **not** with SqlCe.

As it seems, there are [some tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/09/09/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql.aspx) to get it to work, but I never tried it myself...no idea if it works as well as with the "real" SQL Server.
So I guess Entity Framework would be the safer choice.

Comment: Yes, no problem, I run SqlMetal which produces the necessary classes/files.